# To check whether Active MQ is up and running in Mule ESB

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic

I listen to an ActiveMQ, connected to Mule ESB and process the request. If the queue is down, I dont receive any request. I need to check on scheduled interval whether the queue is up and running and send a notification email if the queue is down. Can someone help me on the same?

Comment: Are you using Mule management console (MMC) to deploy your Mule application?

Comment: I am using maven/Jenkins for deployment. Not using MMC.